# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python

Como soluciono el error

```
def extraer_codigo_python_de_exe(exe_archivo):
  """Extrae el código Python de un archivo ejecutable.

  Args:
    exe_archivo: La ruta al archivo ejecutable.

  Devuelve:
    El código Python que se incrustó en el archivo ejecutable.
  """

  # Abre el archivo ejecutable.
  pe = pefile.PE(exe_archivo)

  # Obtiene la sección .text del archivo ejecutable.
  texto_seccion = pe.get_section_by_index(1)

  # Obtiene los datos crudos de la sección .text.
  texto_datos = texto_seccion.get_data()

  # Decodifica los datos crudos de la sección .text.
  python_codigo = base64.b64decode(texto_datos)

  # Devuelve el código Python.
  return python_codigo
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿qué línea es la que lanza la excepción?

Comment: Deberías indicar, igual que te comentan por arriba otros compañeros, de qué módulo sale `pefile.PE(exe_archivo)`. Esto lo importas de algún sitio. Necesitamos todo el código involucrado para saber qué puede estar sucediendo